# Is taking the reciprocal of a differentiable strictly rigorous?

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, logarithms, exponential-function

I've read a proof of $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in which the reciprocal of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is taken and was wondering if this is strictly rigorous. The proof was: $$y=\ln x$$ $$e^y=x$$ then take the derivative with respect to $y$, so $$e^y=\frac{dx}{dy}$$ then take the reciprocal of the differentiable to give $$\frac{1}{e^y}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and since $e^y=x$, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$$

the question is simply: is taking the reciprocal of a differentiable rigorous? I know considering it as a variable to add or subtract to different sides of an equation, but I (obviously) am not sure about this case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not strictly rigorous, but it does nevertheless give the correct result. This is one of the reasons the fractional notation for the derivative is as popular as it is.

Comment: Unless one of the derivatives is zero, this is perfectly rigorous and just reflects the inverse function theorem.

Comment: So, if I were to use this "trick" (for lack of a better description) to calculate the derivative of some other function, would it still be an acceptable approach, or does it only work for specific examples such as this one? @Arthur

Comment: One can prove that for a differentiable, invertible function $f$, we have $\frac1{\frac{df}{dx}(x)} = \frac{d(f^{-1})}{dx}(f(x))$. So it works in general. Take, for instance, $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0, \infty)$. Then $f'(x) = 2x$. At the same time, $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt x$, and $[f^{-1}]'(x) = \frac1{2\sqrt x}$. We have $\frac{1}{2x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the chain rule.  For a function composition $F=f \circ g$, the rule states $$F'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$.  In other words, if you denote $y=g(x)$ and $z=f(y)$, then $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ Now if $g$ is an invertible function and $f$ is its inverse, then $$F=g^{-1}\circ g$$ is just the identity $F(x)=x$. In other words, $z=x$. Then $$\frac{dz}{dx}=1=\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$ or 
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$ That's why you were okay to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot comment, yet. Therefore, I write an answer. It is not really rigorous as presented here. But if you use the right theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) it works.